# Adding image together with text in a picker view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

Can we add image together with text in a picker view?
Anyone please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In picker view's delegate there is

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
               forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
```

method, where you can create your custom view (may be UIView with UILabel and UIImageView in your case) and return it - so UIPickerView will use it for row representation. See reference for more information.

If you return  `UIView*` in this method you may also need to set its `userInteractionEnabled` property to NO, otherwise picker will not select rows if you tap them.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is Yes. You just do the same as you do with UITableView. Creating a custom view to return to the delegate method is all you need to do.