# how to display image along with values in pickerview in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

how to display image along with values in pickerview in iPhone SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may refer to this answer : [Adding image together with text in a picker view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532490/adding-image-together-with-text-in-a-picker-view)